# Why is sprintf with a %llu returning the letters "lu"?

Tags: string, gcc, printf, c99, stm32cubeide

```
uint64_t milliSeconds =getTimeMs64();
int timestringLength = 0;

timestringLength = snprintf( pBuffer, bufferSize, "%llu", milliSeconds );
```

Um, I'm more than confused. About to walk the disassembly for snprintf() but figured I'd concurrently ask smarter people.

All I want is to send this unsigned 64bit, and get a string. Instead, I get timestringLength == `2` and my buffer has the letters `lu` on top. I don't know how this is happening.

I have build flags in Eclipse/CDT for `-std=c99`, so it's not a c90 issue. I tried with `long long unsigned` instead of `uint64_t`.

STM32CubeMxIDE (Eclipse v20210303, CDT 10.x), GCC, built for c99. Probably something stupid, but figured I'd ask while I had a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured, it was something easy. In STM32CubeIDE, there is a compiler flag that defines runtime library specifications, STM or CDT calls this option `Runtime Library`.

If it's set to `Reduced C (--specs=nano.specs)` snprintf() will not be able to handle %llu and surely others (I only tested %d that did seem to work).

Set this option to `Standard C` if you are going to use snprintf.[image]